# Decide if a number is even or odd by using bitwise operator

Tags: bitwise, assembly

The following exercise is from an Assembler-course I'm taking:

> Write a program that takes a number x as input, and returns:
>
> - 0 if x is even.
> - 1 if x is odd.

Full exercise-page here: [GitHub](https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex/blob/master/4_basic_assembly/2_bitwise_operations/2_practical_bit_games/ex/3_write_code/write_code.txt)

Here's my solution:

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc' 

; ===============================================
section '.text' code readable executable

start:

    call    read_hex        ; Provided by the teacher. Reads a hexadecimal number from stdin.

    and     eax,    0x1

    cmp     eax,    0x0 
    je      print_result

    mov     eax,    0x1
print_result:
    call    print_eax_binary    ; Provided by the teacher. Prints a binary number to stdout.

    ; Exit the process:
    push    0
    call    [ExitProcess]

include 'training.inc'
```

I would say it works alright:

[image]

- Is my solution valid?
- Can it be improved? Respectively, is there a better solution possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Simplify your code

This can certainly be simplified.  Keep the goal in mind: get either 0 or 1 into `EAX`.  Once you've executed this instruction:

```
and     eax,    0x1
```

That's exactly what you have.  So that means all of this can be deleted:

```
    cmp     eax,    0x0 
    je      print_result

    mov     eax,    0x1
print_result:
```

And all you need to do is print the result:

```
call    print_eax_binary
```